# using relative references to set a range to a variable vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
y = 3
For x = 1 To 600
If Cells(x, y) = "CD Sector Average" Then
    CDPerc = Cells(x, y + 7).Value
    CDComp = Cells(x, y + 9).Range: Cells(x, y + 20).Range
End If
```

This is just part of what I am doing but I want to set the range of cells in the same row as that text 9 columns to the right to 20 as the variable. There is other data in the row so I cant set the entire row to the variable either.  Is there a way I can do this without setting each cell to a different variable?

Comment: Why can't you do this directly on the worksheet?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do. It seems to me like you're already doing what you want. Unless you want to remove CDPerc and CDComp? If that's the case I'd have to know what they are. (also if you CDComp is a range shouldn't you use "Set CDComp ="?)

Answer (score 0):

If `CDComp` is a `Range` then you want:

```
Set CDComp = Range(Cells(x, y + 9), Cells(x, y + 20))
```

or if it's a `Variant` and you are trying to load an array:

```
CDComp = Range(Cells(x, y + 9), Cells(x, y + 20)).Value
```